# Install mod_wsgi to actual Apache instance on CentOS 7

Tags: apache, centos7, mod-wsgi

I have a VPS server with CentOS 7. I have on it two PHP websites working OK on several VirtualHosts and now I want to deploy a Django (Python3) project, so I need mod_wsgi module.

If I do `systemctl status httpd` I get this response [image: get this response] so Apache is installed and running (and serving my PHP websites).

But if I do `yum install mod_wsgi` CentOS tell me that I need to install httpd package. If I install the httpd package, then the PHP not works and can't start httpd service anymore.

If I execute `whereis httpd` I get `httpd: /opt/apache/bin/httpd /opt/ferozo/bin/httpd`

Comment: This is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow. It should be posted to https://superuser.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/. In either case, make sure to check the corresponding on-topic pages: [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) & [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: what command did you use to install apache on your system?

Answer (score 1):

I get it solved without reinstalling entire httpd.

1. Update server using `yum update -y`
2. Install Python3.6 following [this steps](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-python-3-6-4-on-centos-7/)
3. Download manually, compile and install mod_wsgi module following [this steps](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/master/user-guides/quick-installation-guide.html) **important note: in my case I have to indicate manually the path of Apache and Python when do `./configure`**
4. Then edit httpd.conf to load mod_wsgi.so module
5. Restart Apache service with `systemctl restart httpd` and now Apache is running with mod_wsgi module enabled!

Answer (score 0):

### Take backup before doing this. (I am not responsible for any data loss)

You will have to copy your config files to /etc/httpd after doing the following commands. You will have to setup everything again.

First remove the version of apache you are using.

You will have to reinstall apache using:

```
yum install httpd
```

And then install mod_wsgi using:

```
yum install mod_wsgi
```

And to install PHP:

```
yum install php
```